# Unexpected value 'HttpTestingController' imported by the module 'DynamicTestModule'. Please add an @NgModule annotation

Tags: angular, unit-testing, jasmine, httpclient

```
describe('ComponentHttpRServiceComponent', () => {
  let component: ComponentHttpRServiceComponent;
  let fixture: ComponentFixture<ComponentHttpRServiceComponent>;

  let service: StudentService;
  let httpclient: HttpClient;
  // let httptestcontroller: HttpTestingController; <--

  beforeEach(async () => {
    await TestBed.configureTestingModule({
      declarations: [ComponentHttpRServiceComponent],
      imports: [HttpClientTestingModule],// HttpTestingController <--
      providers: [StudentService],
    }).compileComponents();
  });

  beforeEach(() => {
    fixture = TestBed.createComponent(ComponentHttpRServiceComponent);
    component = fixture.componentInstance;
    fixture.detectChanges();
    service = TestBed.inject(StudentService);
    // httptestcontroller = TestBed.inject(HttpTestingController); <--
  });

  it('should create', () => {
    expect(component).toBeTruthy();
  });

  it('httpclient get method', () => {});
});
```

whenever I add the HttpTestingController inside the imports array, I get an error written as Unexpected value 'HttpTestingController' imported by the module 'DynamicTestModule'. Please add an @NgModule annotation.

how to resolve the above issue?

Comment: Try adding it to the providers list rather than the imports list

Comment: @R.Richards thanks I was adding to both the imports and providers the same time after doing little google

Comment: HttpTestingController isn't a module, so having it in the imports list doesn't work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to add `HttpTestingController` anywhere, neither `imports` nor `providers`, you just need to add `HttpClientTestingModule` in `imports` which you already did.

`HttpTestingController` is part of `HttpClientTestingModule`, So you will get the `HttpTestingController` in the below line, just uncomment it then you are good to go.

```js
httptestcontroller = TestBed.inject(HttpTestingController);
```

Here is the full configuration

```js
//*Removed extra code for readability
beforeEach(async () => {
  await TestBed.configureTestingModule({
    imports: [HttpClientTestingModule],
  }).compileComponents();
});

beforeEach(() => {
  httptestcontroller = TestBed.inject(HttpTestingController);
});
```